# Strange result in modelling magnetic levitation system?? Negative Transfer function?

Tags: arduino, electromagnetism, control, control-system, matlab

I'm working on this magnetic levitation system project where I basically levitate an object under an electromagnet using an Arduino. Currently, I'm stuck at the graphical simulation of my transfer function as it is going down to -18 x 10^152 on MATLAB??

To make sense of this, I initially made a mathematical model of my system using Newton's second order equation of motion to make a mechanical representation of how my system would work. In short, it would be

$$mx" = mg - f(x, i)$$

- where mx" is basically MA in F = MA but already in second order
- mg is the weight of the ball
- f(x , i) is the force of the electromagnet as a function of x and i, being displacement and current.

I checked out the relevant papers similar to what I'm doing, Magnetic Levitation, and found that most use an inductance storage equation(Faraday) to model the force given by the inductor. In short, you get the first attached image. ***see* Figure 1**
[image]

Taken from T.H. Wong's paper: Design of a Magnetic Levitation Control System???An Undergraduate Project.

Link: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5570565

**Figure 1**

Since this was not linearized, the next thing to do was to linearize it using the Taylor Series, which would result in the second attached image. ***see* Figure 2.**

[image]

Taken from Ahamed Khan *et al*'s paper: PID Controller design for a Magnetic Levitation system

Link: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8986710

**Figure 2**

After that, an assumption which resulted in the removal of the static term C(i/x)^2, this assumption was that as mg was the weight of the ball, C(i/x)^2 would be the force required to lift the ball, with the other linear terms being the dynamics to make the system stable. To not go off on a tangent, $$C = mg\frac{x^2}{i^2}$$

I now have everything, I laplace transform the system to get $$ms^2X(s) = -2C(i/x^3)I(s) + 2C(i^2/x^3)X(s)$$

Re-arranging the terms into X(s)/I(s) got me a negative denominator, in which I thought was weird for the first time but I continued regardless. I got the third image as a result.

[image: ControlTheory - Strange result in modelling magnetic levitation system?? Negative Transfer function?]

Taken from Ahamed Khan *et al*'s paper: PID Controller design for a Magnetic Levitation system

Link: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8986710

**Figure 3**

After that was just me inputting my values in:

- m = 6.68 grams -> 6.68x10^-3 kg
- x = 8mm -> 8x10x10^-3 m
- i = 1 A
- C = mg(x/i)^2 = 4.19x10^-6 Nm^2/A^2

[image]

**Figure 4, result**

[image]

**Figure 5. Simulink test**

I got the fourth figure as a result. When I ran it on Simulink, I got the fifth figure. This is way different compared to those other papers, and I'm not even sure what I got wrong or what I'm even supposed to do.

Bibliography (Other papers which basically do the same thing but right):

1. https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5570565
2. https://addi.ehu.es/bitstream/handle/10810/36694/MasterThesis.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y
3. https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8986710
4. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2405896316301513
5. https://www.slideshare.net/SalimAlOufi/mse6183finalprojectwriteupslso05052015rev2#:%7E:text=This%20project%20is%20about%20controlling%20the%20position%20of,feedback%20of%20the%20position%20of%20the%20magnetic%20ball.?msclkid=ed73953da6fd11eca322287678e98ddb

Comment: I can't view the linked document, but if you get a complex root with a positive real part then maybe it's a sign, somewhere.

Comment: Have you seen this https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/magnetic-levitation-formula.833813/ and int the note ... http://blog.sina.com.cn/s/blog_71afdbfd0100ssuk.html (arduino PID)